# How to create this Expandable tip box in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a Flutter project and trying to create an expandable tip box similar to the one shown in the reference image below:

[image]

However, my current implementation is facing overflow issues, and the icon is not aligned properly, as shown in this result image:

[image]

Here's the relevant code:

```
Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.03999999910593033),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
              ),
              child: const Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 280,
                              child: Text(
                                  'Download one of the files below. Open the file in Excel or a similar app, add user info, save, and upload.\n',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  )),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 5),
                            Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down)
                          ],
                        ),
                        Text("Avoid common errors"),
                        BulletedText(
                            "You can upload up to 249 users per CSV file."),
                        BulletedText(
                            "Each user must have a unique username email address."),
                        BulletedText(
                            "Save as a CSV (comma delimited) file with 10 columns.​"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 10),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 24,
                    height: 24,
                    child: Stack(children: []),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
```

Could you provide guidance on how to resolve the overflow issues and properly align the icon within the tip box? I want to achieve a layout similar to the reference image. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          decoration: ShapeDecoration(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.03999999910593033),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
          ),
          child: const Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Text(
                              'Download one of the files below. Open the file in Excel or a similar app, add user info, save, and upload.\n',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                              )),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 5),
                        Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down)
                      ],
                    ),
                    Text("Avoid common errors"),
                    Text(
                        "You can upload up to 249 users per CSV file."),
                    Text(
                        "Each user must have a unique username email address."),
                    Text(
                        "Save as a CSV (comma delimited) file with 10 columns.​"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10),
              SizedBox(
                width: 24,
                height: 24,
                child: Stack(children: []),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
```

Hope this solution works for you

Comment: it's still not in the right corner, and changing sizedbox width only pushing awy the main text insted of the icon

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the first child of the `Row` widget with `Flexible`. Here is the code snippet.

```
Expanded(
         child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                crossAxisAlignment: 
                           CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Flexible(
                                    child: SizedBox(
                                      width: 280,
                                      child: Text(
                                          'Download one of the files below. Open the file in Excel or a similar app, add user info, save, and upload.\n',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                          )),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(width: 5),
                                  Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down)
                                ],
                              ),
                              Text("Avoid common errors"),
                              Text(
                                  "You can upload up to 249 users per CSV file."),
                              Text(
                                  "Each user must have a unique username email address."),
                              Text(
                                  "Save as a CSV (comma delimited) file with 10 columns.​"),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
```

Please mark this as accepted if it helped you. Cheers. You can even scrap the `SizedBox` with `width as 280` and let the `Text` take the width as per the screen width.